# How can I split a Git commit into two if I can come up with the intermediate commit?

Tags: git

A change was applied to a large codebase, then a formatter was applied, touching nearly every file.

```
A --------- B
```

A single commit `B` combining those two actions lead to a gigantic diff that is a pain to review, and also difficult to split up manually with an interactive rebase and picking out hunks. However, I could easily contrive an intermediate commit `I` by checking out `A` and running the code formatter on that.

```
A --------- B
 \ 
  \
   -- I
```

Given that I just made the commit `I`, how can I easily generate a commit `B'` that ends up with the exact same tree content as `B`?

```
A --------- B
 \            
  \           
   -- I --- B' # (has exact same contents as B)
```

If I naively do

```
git checkout B
git rebase I
```

I end up with a ton of conflicts. I don't want to have to be clever at all, I just want to end up at the exact same directory as `B`, with the assumption that the `I..B` diff will be dramatically smaller than `A..B`.

Comment: `git checkout I && git checkout B -- . && git commit -m "Copy of B"`

Comment: @NickT: I think phd provided the answer you are looking for

Comment: @phd Your method leaves files that are in `I`, but not in `B`, in the commit. If files must be removed you could insert `git rm -rf --cached .` between the checkouts; that removes the files from the commit, but still leaves them in the worktree and must be removed from there by some other means, `git clean` for example.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, if you already have I and B, you can do this:

```
git checkout --detach B
git reset --soft I # move branch pointer (HEAD pointer, in this case) to I, set all differences in index ready to be committed
git commit -m "blah blah"
```

Now you can point whatever branch you want where you are if you like the results:

```
git branch -f blah
git checkout blah
```

Comment: This is a good method since it works with the "user accessible" command line API. I like to go straight to `git commit-tree` as it lets you build the resulting commit from the parts you have, in a very direct manner, but then you have to fast-forward or reset to the resulting commit afterward.

Comment: I used to do commit-tree a lot... but then I discovered `reset --soft` and my life was not the same since. Much simpler to use.... would definitely fall back to `commit-tree` if need arises in the future.

Comment: The OP definitely said he created commits, and did not mention branches, but I think he implied that `B` and `I` were actually branch names ; in that case I would go with @phd 's solution (posted as a comment below the OP's question)

Comment: Glory to our new moderator! \o/

Comment: It's been a looong journey (actually, you made it before I did, congrats!). Next stop: git's gold badge :-)

Comment: ... but with torek and you snooping around to take the points I so rightfully _deserve_, it will be a while till we get there. :-D

Answer (score 1):

Just to mention the `commit-tree` solution hinted at by torek in comment above :

```
git reset --hard $(git commit-tree -m "Did this and that" -p I $(git rev-parse B^{tree}))
```

[`git commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree) takes here 3 parameters to create a new commit :

`-m "Did this and that"` to give your `B'` commit a message
`-p I` to set his parent (`I`)
and lastly
`$(git rev-parse B^{tree})` (without a flag because it's the main (mandatory) parameter) to indicate the tree it should have

The `reset --hard` command sets current branch on this new commit. So you can choose to execute it either on your current branch to be "repaired" or on a new branch created for that purpose.